# Renaming program, or its working directory, changes behavior?

Tags: windows, windows-10, c++, directx

This is definitely the strangest bug I've been banging my head against in a good long while...

I have an extremely simple .exe on Windows 10 that I compiled myself using MSVC and the Allegro library (which uses DirectX). The source is below in case the details are somehow important, but the gist is:

- DirectDraw throws a runtime error when I run the code.
- If I rename the executable, the error goes away and the program runs successfully.
- If I move the executable to a different folder, or rename the folder, the program runs successfully.
- If I rename the executable/folder back to their original names, the error returns.

There are no other files in the folder. The only thing I can think of is that Windows is somehow looking up the **absolute path** of the executable and behaving differently depending on this value (caching some compatibility information?)

Any idea what is going on? In practice I can simply rename the executable and go about my day, but now I'm really curious about why this behavior is happening...

PS: The code is exactly the following, using the Allegro 4.4 library.

```
#include "allegro.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    allegro_init();
    set_color_depth(8);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_FULLSCREEN, 640, 480, 0, 0);
    exit(0);
}
END_OF_MAIN()
```

When I run the code, I get an error (E_NOIMPL) when I try to set the video mode.

Comment: What is the name of the executable when it causes problems?

Comment: @Mokubai "alleg_test.exe"

Comment: @Dave now that you've taken the time to edit and downvote my question over a triviality, perhaps I could beseech you for some professional help or advice, as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should know that windows stores the full path to the program in the registry or desktop.  If you rearrange the name of the proggie, or the directory, you need to search registry for the name of the program.

One place worth looking at is a thing called APPPATHS, where you can create shortcuts to the desired program.  You make a copy of write.exe, and replace the string in it (wordpad.exe) to a name out of use (eg zdirectx.exe), and create an entry in the apppath registry, that will launch `directx.exe` when you call `zdirectx.exe`.  You can then call your program `directx.exe` too.

I use this technique to move a lot of program stuff off-path, while still keeping the program accessable.